# How to prevent Ubuntu from becoming unresponsive when not having enough memory?

Tags: ram, swap, memory-usage

When I open an application for which there is not enough memory, Ubuntu becomes unresponsive. The problem seems to arise from the way Ubuntu handles swap (as `kswapd` hogs CPU usage in such a situation). Other operating systems I've used such as Windows or Mac OS warn you when there is not enough RAM available but in Ubuntu the system becomes unresponsive for quite a while. Sometimes I have to restart the computer.

I've had this problem with various versions of Ubuntu from Hardy Heron and with several different computers with different RAM sizes.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything as user here.

Comment: OK, I'll ask the obvious. How much RAM do you have? What is your swapfile size set to? What size and how fast is your hard drive (5400/7200 rpm)? What flavor/version of 'buntu are you running?

Comment: Xubuntu 14.04, 4GB RAM, 3GB swap, SSD.

Comment: @user.dz I've asked this elsewhere but never got an answer... when the comments get too long, and the system hasn't already asked us to move to chat, how can I force it to move to chat? Also, if you're just making a comment without @, doesn't the OP always get notified? (I didn't understand the >< around my name either.)

Comment: Reza did you ever get an answer to your question? I missed your original response because you didn't have @heynnema at the start of the comment. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

to turn off the swap.

Comment: Please any reason why `swapoff -a` helps the situation?